# What do I have to configure on my server to increase security from default?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, security, configuration, defaults

I am setting up a Windows 2003 machine to host a website, are there any settings that I should pay special attention to in regards to security?

In other words, is there dangerous default setting I should know about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NSA puts out a comprehensive guide to securing operating systems.  While not every option will be required for your environment, the explanations about each change are helpful in understanding the reasons for it.  [NSA - Operating Systems Guide](http://www.nsa.gov/ia/guidance/security_configuration_guides/operating_systems.shtml)

You can also check out the [SANS Reading Room](http://www.sans.org/reading_room/) for papers written on a broader range of topics, but primarily with a security focus.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft have excellent baseline security checklists, and there are compliance tools.

The one for Windows 2003 is [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc163140.aspx)